# elsarticle.cls not found when using TexMaker, but texlive-latex-extra is installed

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, linux, elsarticle

I am trying to get my TeX document to build.  I know this works because I've done it on another system, but I recently put Lubuntu on my Linux partition, so everything is new again.

I've installed Texmaker as well as `texlive` and `texlive-latex-extra` and a few other related LaTeX packages.  `elsarticle.cls` is supposed to be part of `texlive-latex-extra` but when I quick build my document I still get

```
! LaTeX Error: File `elsarticle.cls' not found.
```

Is there something I have to do to tell Texmaker that I've installed extra packages, and that it can look for `elsarticle.cls` in `texlive-latex-extra`?  How do I fix this?

Additional info: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBcJO.png) are screenshots of my Texmaker settings.  Please let me know if I should include anything else.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What does `kpsewhich elsarticle.cls` give you?

Comment: @Mico Nothing.  A blank line.

Comment: In that case `elsarticle.cls` was not installed in a folder that's searched by your TeX distribution. (Maybe it wasn't installed at all...) Try downloading the basic files from [the CTAN page](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle) and running the file `elsarticle.ins` through LaTeX to create `elsarticle.cls`.

Comment: @Mico I did what it said and put the .cls and *.bst files in `/usr/local/share/texmf/` but it still doesn't seem to work.  When I `kpsewhich elsarticle.cls` in that directory it finds it but not from the directory my TeX document is in.  Should I be using a different directory to contain `elsarticle.cls`?

Comment: After installing the files, did you update the filename database of your TeX distribution? Hint: `texhash` might do the job.)

Comment: @Mico I did that, but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: for a test copy the `elsarticle.cls` in your documents directory. Did it run without a problem?

Comment: Moving the cls file to /usr/share/latex/texmf/elsevier/ and running texhash after that worked for me in CentOS 7

Answer (score 45):

`elsarticle` is not included in `texlive-latex-extra` http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/texlive-latex-extra/filelist, but in `texlive-publishers` packages http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/texlive-publishers/filelist. So, you need to install it first. Run this command on `terminal`

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-publishers
```

and then try compile your document again.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Texlive-Science solved the problem. Try `sudo apt install texlive-science`.
*My version: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-extra/2017.20180305-2*

Comment: Please see that this question is 6 years old. Your answer may be valid for a current version of TeX Live, but it may not valid for an old version six years ago ... Please add your used TeX Live version number (simply copy the first line of a resulting `*.log` file to your answer) ...