# In *nix based systems, how does LaTeX recursively look for classes / styles?

Tags: tex-core

Broadly speaking, how does LaTeX look for class and styles in a *nix based system?

More specifically, `export TEXMFHOME='~/.config/texmf'` followed by `texhash ~/.config/texmf` is not referenced when I call one of my own classes or styles. Interestingly, even if TEXMFHOME remains as I have just described, LaTeX will still search ~/texmf/tex/latex/local/ for classes and styles. That leads me to believe that it will always look there but perhaps I am wrong.

So, how does LaTeX search for classes / styles? Which folders does it look within, and how do you edit those settings?

EDIT: Unlike other questions, I am also wondering how to edit these recursive settings, either by declaring variables or editing config files.

Comment: Many TeX implementations on those systems relies, for file lookup, on the [kpathsea library](http://tug.org/kpathsea/), whose behavior is detailed in the [kpathsea manual](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html).

Comment: Have you read, for example, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262246/69818)?

Comment: You should *never* do `mktexlsr` on `TEXMFHOME`.

Comment: @egreg how come?